# How to change the look of a disabled JButton in java

Tags: java, colors, jbutton

I am making a game and when I disable a button with  `setEnabled(false);` the buttons turns grey which clashes with the other colors in the game. Is their a way to change the color of the button when it is disabled?

Answer (score 8):

You can add HTML coding to your button which gives a large range of flexibility, even to disabled buttons.

```
Example: button.setText("<html><font color = red>3</font></html>");
```

Comment: Works fine as a quick workaround! I had the same problem as the question starter, I was programming a small game which makes use of disabled buttons a lot.

Comment: This won't work in all cases. I'm using FlatLaf and JDK 11 and this does not work. I cannot confirm that it works in any cases, but I take the word of @Bernd and the poster of this answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about the text, then you might be able to use the UIManager to change the disabled foreground color. Check out the [UIManager Defaults](http://www.camick.com/java/blog.html?name=uimanager-defaults).

Answer (score 4):

Calling **setContentAreaFilled(false)** on a button will make a button look as if it is disabled, even if it is not. It doesn't, however, seem to work the other way around.

If you don't need your button to look enabled, then it is a nice fix.

[Docs Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setContentAreaFilled%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 2):

You can also set a disable icon with [JButton.setDisableIcon()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setDisabledIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29)

Answer (score 2):

The button's `ButtonUI` controls the disabled text color. Luckily, you can change it:

```
button1.setUI(new MetalButtonUI() {
    protected Color getDisabledTextColor() {
        return Color.BLUE;
    }
});
button1.setEnabled(false);
button2.setUI(new MetalButtonUI() {
    protected Color getDisabledTextColor() {
        return Color.RED;
    }
});
button2.setEnabled(false);
```

**NB:** The default UI class used by JButton is ButtonUI

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to modify the [Look and Feel](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/) you are using.  There are tons available for download and you can of course make your own.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easy solution is:

```
yourButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
```

Easily reverted by just changing the boolean value to true:

```
yourButton.setContentAreaFilled(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

i am not 100% on this, but i think you can overwrite the paint method of the button's glasspane to overlay it with the color of your choice.

here is a tutorial on the panes of a container:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html

Comment: Individual components don't have a glasspane. The glasspane is for the entire frame.