# How to change the color of a disabled jbutton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, uimanager

I'm implementing a Mastermind game and there is a board which has the plays (left) and the results (right).
I have numerous buttons which some are enabled and other disabled.
These buttons are associated to the colors of a play or a result.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2L94.jpg "working board"
In the image, there are 2 types of buttons, the enabled, green boarded, and the disabled, red boarded.
When I try to use an UImanager, the nimbus, it puts all the disabled buttons of the same color, and I don't want that.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSO4T.jpg "not working board"

I've tried to simply setBackground of a button and it didn't work.

How can I put a specific color to a button and only that button using the UIManager?
That way I can have each button with it's color.

Comment: There are several suggestions [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590764/how-to-change-the-look-of-a-disabled-jbutton-in-java)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An button can't be changed while using UIManager.