# Why can't I change the JButton (disabled) text color?

Tags: java, swing

I started programming Java. This is my first window application. I did a simple tic-tac-toe game and I want the "o" button font color to be a different color. But it doesn't work. I can change the background color, but not the fonts, why?

```
package moje;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Kolko_i_krzyzyk extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    
    static JTextField tekst;
    static JLayeredPane ekran = new JLayeredPane();
    static JButton button = new JButton();
    static int licznik=0;

    
    public Kolko_i_krzyzyk () {
        super("Kółko i krzyżyk");
        ekran = new JLayeredPane();
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(800, 800);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        
        //Siatka podzielona 3 na 3
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        
        //Tworzenie 9 przycisków
        for(int i = 1; i<=9; i++) {
        JButton button = new JButton();
        add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame okno = new Kolko_i_krzyzyk();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton  button = (JButton) e.getSource();
    if(licznik%2==0 ) {
        button.setText("x");
        button.setFont(new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 90));
    }
    else {
        button.setText("O");
        button.setForeground(Color.RED);
        button.setFont(new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 90));
    }
    button.setEnabled(false);
    licznik++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue here is the default behavior when disabling the `JButton` via `setEnabled(false)`.
This will grey out the button and ignore any color formatting you did to the text (foreground).

There are several workarounds to modify this behavior (as seen in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590764/how-to-change-the-look-of-a-disabled-jbutton-in-java)).

Here is a short demonstration (without the final game logic of course) , which changes the UI of the `JButton` via `setUI()`.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalButtonUI;

public class Test {

    private int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Test().buildGui());
    }

    private void buildGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            JButton button = new JButton() {
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(150, 150);
                }
            };
            button.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 90));
            panel.add(button);
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (counter % 2 == 0) {
                        button.setText("X");
                        button.setUI(new MetalButtonUI() {
                            // override the disabled text color for the button UI
                            protected Color getDisabledTextColor() {
                                return Color.BLUE;
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        button.setText("O");
                        button.setUI(new MetalButtonUI() {
                            protected Color getDisabledTextColor() {
                                return Color.RED;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    button.setEnabled(false);
                    counter++;
                }
            });
        }
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Another (simpler) way to do it would be to build some `ImageIcon`s for "X" and "O", then set these on the buttons via `setIcon()`/`setDisabledIcon()`. This would save you the trouble from modifying the button UI.

Comment: Nice one! More comprehensive than I was expecting. :)

Comment: Thanks :) I appreciate the feedback.